# calculating percentage of sales profit in SQL

Tags: sql

```
Product Group   Product ID         Sales      Profit
    A             6797              1,000      200 
    A             6745                500       90 
    B             1278                200       60 
    B             1245              1,500      350 
    C             7890                650       80 
    D             4587                350       50
```

Q1). Filter out product IDs that contribute to top 80% of the total profit of their respective group.

Comment: what you want desired output , please shown?????

Comment: show at least what you have tried. so we can help you.

Comment: If we do your homework for you, how will you learn?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what rdbms you are using you can get the output in SQL server in this way. You can get profit for a group and use aggregate function to compare and filter the rows.

```
select 'A' as Product_group, 6797  as ProductID,  1000    as Sales ,  200   as Profit into #temp1 union all 
select 'A' as Product_group, 6745  as ProductID,      500  as Sales ,    90 as Profit union all 
select 'B' as Product_group, 1278  as ProductID,      200  as Sales ,    60 as Profit union all 
select 'B' as Product_group, 1245  as ProductID,  1500    as Sales ,  350   as Profit union all 
select 'C' as Product_group, 7890  as ProductID,      650  as Sales ,    80 as Profit union all 
select 'D' as Product_group, 4587  as ProductID,      350  as Sales ,    50 as Profit  


select t.Product_group, t.ProductID, sum(t.sales) totalsles, sum(t.profit) totalProfit, sum(Profit_grp) Groupprofit   from #temp1 t 
join  (select Product_group,  sum(sales) totalsles_group, sum(profit) Profit_grp from #temp1 t1 group by Product_group) t1 on t1.Product_group = t.Product_group 
group by t.Product_group, t.ProductID  
having sum(t.profit) *1.0/ sum(t1.Profit_grp) *1.0 >= 0.8
```

Output: I added group profit just to compare. You can remove the aggregate and add in group by if you would like

```
Product_group   ProductID   totalsles   totalProfit Groupprofit
B                   1245    1500            350      410
C                   7890    650             80       80
D                    4587   350             50       50
```

Comment: select productgroup, productid, percentag from (select p.productgroup,p.productid,p.profit,((p.profit*100)/su) as percentag from products p
 left join  ( select q.productgroup as PG , sum(profit) as su from products q group by q.productgroup)q
 ON p.productgroup = PG)q where percentag >80;

Comment: @sarathsp I did not understand .. could you please explain ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may works out:

```
with CTE as(
select [Product Group], sum([Sales]) as Tolsum from Table 
group by [Product Group]

select prod.*,
sum(prod.[Profit]/cte.[Tolsum]) over (Partition by prod.[Product Group] Order by prod.[Product ID]) as contribution
from CTE cte
inner join
Table prod
on
cte.[Product Group] = prod.[Product Group]
having 
sum(prod.[Profit]/cte.[Tolsum]) over (Partition by prod.[Product Group] Order by prod.[Product ID]) < 0.8
```